# java spring mvc project does not start after dependency updates

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, java-8, java-time

I'm trying to use Java Time classes (like Instant, DateTime...) in a Java 8 project with Spring MVC (and Maven)

With these dependencies

```
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
```

the project starts, but I obtain the following exception when querying data using a model class that has LocalDate property:

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 78790C08`

I've read that Hibernate version valid to use Java.Time classes is 5.2.1, so I've updated the pom of the project but when I try to start it, I obtain a white page with no errors on console (I run the project with Intellij Idea).

I suppose it depends on issues between dependencies in the project, I've also tried to upgrade spring framework and security, accordingly to what I've read in https://mvnrepository.com/ but nothing changes.

EDIT:

here it's the complete POM (only properties and dependencies) of the project:

```
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <tiles.version>3.0.8</tiles.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- iReport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Utility -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->


        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: If you use spring framework I recommend to use the `spring-framework-bom` in your dependencyManagement which makes it easier to handle the other dependencies incl. the versions...Also the version you have picked is long out of support https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#support

Comment: Please post your full pom

Comment: @khmarbaise it's a legacy project, and I'm trying to evolve it step by step, I know that that version is out of support
Regarding spring-framework-bom, I will try to use it to solve the issue, but I would also like to understand what is the issue, because it is not clear...

Comment: It looks like you are mixing spring boot versions with different spring framework version which do not belong together... (spring-framework.version and hibernate etc.) ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Spring Boot? Maybe Spring MVC...so how can I understand which versions can I use together with Hibernate?

Comment: Oh sorry of course spring etc. Check the bom files of the spring framework there is mentioned which versions belong together ... best is to use them anyway instead of manually fiddling out the versions....

Comment: @khmarbaise do the bom files let me understand which Hibernate version is compatible with Spring too? Because I suppose that's the point...

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to upgrade the spring framework to version 4.3.x ? [according to this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-4.x) spring version 4.3.x is compatible with hibernate v 5.2.x

Comment: Yes, but still remains the issue. Blank page at startup and no errors anywhere. Are there compatibility issues with other dependencies (other than Spring Framework I mean)? Nobody answers me about it